# index class in different rows in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table

I have a table with buttons on each row. I am trying to click on a button on a particular and it picks the value .claim_value field of the same row and put the value in the td opposite it .vet_value.

Here's my code

```
<table id="tasks" class="col-md-12 table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
          <td>Service</td>
          <td>Key notes</td>
          <td>Claim Amount</td>
          <td>Vetted Amount</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="therow">
          <td class="claim_value">hey</td>
          <td class="vet_value"></td>
          <button class="button">button</button>
        </tr>
        <tr class="therow">
          <td class="claim_value">you</td>
          <td class="vet_value"></td>
          <button class="button">button</button>
        </tr>
        <tr class="therow">
          <td class="claim_value">me</td>
          <td class="vet_value"></td>
          <button class="button">button</button>
        </tr>
        <tr class="therow">
          <td class="claim_value">them</td>
          <td class="vet_value"></td>
          <button class="button">button</button>
        </tr>
    </tbody>    
</table>
```

so i want to be able to click on class="button"

```
$(".button").click(function(){
  (".claim_value").val() of this same row goes into (".vet_value").val()
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just call `parent()` to access the parent `<tr>` element and modify `<td>` from there

```
$(".button").click(function(){
    var $parent=$(this).parent();
    var claimValue=$parent.find(".claim_value").text();
    $parent.find(".vet_value").text(claimValue);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to use `.val()` unless the element is `input` or `textarea`

with `td` use `.text()` also you need to use `$(this)` to refer to the button you clicked and `closest('tr')` to select the closest row then `.find()` to find the element with class you want

```
$(".button").click(function(){
     var claim_value = $(this).closest('tr').find(".claim_value").text();
     $(this).closest('tr').find(".vet_value").text(claim_value);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `html()` that is not `val()`. Insert `td` inside which has to be the direct child of `tr`. As val() only comes for `input` and `textarea`.

```js
$(".button").click(function(){
  alert($(this).closest('tr').find(".claim_value").html());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tasks" class="col-md-12 table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
          <td>Service</td>
          <td>Key notes</td>
          <td>Claim Amount</td>
          <td>Vetted Amount</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="therow">
          <td class="claim_value">hey</td>
          <td class="vet_value"></td>
          <td>
          <button class="button">button</button>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="therow">
          <td class="claim_value">you</td>
          <td class="vet_value"></td>
          <td>
          <button class="button">button</button>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="therow">
          <td class="claim_value">me</td>
          <td class="vet_value"></td>
          <td>
          <button class="button">button</button>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="therow">
          <td class="claim_value">them</td>
          <td class="vet_value"></td>
          <td>
          <button class="button">button</button>
          </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>    
</table>
```

Comment: Can we use parent instead of closest? that will work too right?

Comment: We can. But the latest jquery uses `closest`

Comment: @kannan * the `parent()` method traverses to the immediate parent of each of these elements in the DOM tree and constructs a new jQuery object from the matching elements.This method is similar to `.parents(),` except .parent() only travels a single level up the DOM tree* .. Some think like `.find()` and `.children()` `.find()` find any element in tree but `.children()` the direct child the DOM tree .. **So on this OP code case** we can use `.parent()` cause we need to just travels a single level up

Comment: Thanks @Mohamed-Yousef